# Error message from Wine

Tags: wine, kubuntu

I installed the Pokerstars game through the Wine and Playonlinux programs. When i start the Pokerstars game i get an error message from Wine that after i close it everything goes well without receiving any more errors or closing the game.
I use a laptop with integrated graphics AMD , Kubuntu 20.04.1 , `wine-5.0 Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1` , `playonlinux 4.3.4` .

My question is if this error message is normal and i don't have to worry about it or if someone who has the game installed has the same error ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYWiZ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `PokerStarsBr.exe` file and now when i open the game i don't get the error. The file is in the `PlayonLinux's virtual drives` then search for the folder you created for Pokerstars installation. I tested the game without this file and everything works fine without errors.